# How to find cursor of a specific timestamp?

Tags: horizon, javascript-sdk

I need to find what's the cursor of a **specific** timestamp in order to let my users see their transactions by date.

Is there any function in an SDK or any endpoint on horizon server?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK this functionality doesn't yet exist. There is [an issue](https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/42) raised last year to enable it. It has been worked on and is tagged `in-orbit`. (I'm not sure what that means).